# Undefined variables (passing parameters)

Tags: php, variables, parameters

so I have a page lets say product.php where some of the variables are dependent from parameters being passed from another page lets say input.php . However if a user type in the URL like mysite/product.php , these variables now become undefined because they are defined from parameters being passed from input.php. How do I handle this kind of error? or what kind of concepts do I have to explore more.

Comment: How are variables "being passed" from input.php to product.php? Most likely you need a session and to use session variables to store the data between requests.

Comment: Do you mean parameters in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to check if variable exist and pass it to function like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_var'])){
    //variable exist
    $myFunction($_POST['my_var']);
} else {
    //return to page where user should submit values
}
```